# What happens to a list reference when item is set

Tags: python, dictionary, variable-assignment

```
def foo():
    testdict = {'A': '1235', 'B': '6458', 'C': 54156}
    dofoo(testdict)

def dofoo(testdict):
    testdict['A'] = testdict['A'].replace('2', '')
```

What happened with the reference to the value of the `testdict` variable when `testdict['A']` has been set? Did only that item lost reference to the original value?

**Edit:**

Because if I would do:

```
def foo():
    testdict = {'A': '1235', 'B': '6458', 'C': 54156}
    dofoo(testdict)

def dofoo(testdict)
    testdict = {'F' : '156', 'G' : '6875'}
```

Then the reference would be lost. So why not if you set an item of such collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand what values you're referring to with a given name, at any given time. Here's what I mean:

```
def doFoo1(testdict):
    testdict["A"] = "test1" # this changes a value contained in testdict
    print(id(testdict)) # the id

def doFoo2(testdict):
    testdict = {some:"new dict"} # this creates a new dict object
    print(id(testdict)) # prints a different id, since testdict is a new object

def foo():
    mydict = {'A': '1235', 'B': '6458', 'C': 54156}
    print(id(mydict))
    doFoo1(mydict)
    print(id(mydict))
    doFoo2(mydict)
    print(id(mydict))
```

Here's the output on my system (64-bit Python 3.3 on Windows 7):

```
>>> foo()
59383560
59383560
59383560
59413832
59383560
```

There are five `id` values printed, three (the first, third and fifth) from `foo` and one from each of the `doFoo` functions (the second and fourth). The one from doFoo2 is the only one that isn't the same as the others, because the statement `testdict = {some:"new dict"}` created a new object that was bound to the `testdict` name inside that function's namespace. That change isn't reflected back in the `foo` function, because it's `mydict` name is still bound to the original object.

This is a part of Python that is different than most other programming languages. Unlike C where a variable name corresponds to a specific location in memory, in Python a name refers to a specific object. If you assign to the name again, that simply rebinds the name to a different object (without affecting the original object at all, though it might be garbage collected if there are no other references to it).

A section of this [Code like a Pythonista](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) presentation is very helpful in understand this distinction. I think it's "nametag" metaphor is very good for understanding how name binding works in Python.

Answer (score 2):

```
testdict = {'A': '1235', 'B': '6458', 'C': 54156}

def foo(x):
    x['A'] = 0;

foo(testdict)

print testdict['A']
```

The output for testdict['A'] is 0.

This is because the dict is passed as a reference into the foo function.

So when you pass testdict to foo, x is not a new dict that is a copy of testdict - it's actually a pointer going to the same testdict. When x['A'] changes, that means testdict['A'] also changes.

Comment: But if I would set testdict = {'just', 'something'} in def dofoo. Then the reference would be lost. So why wouldn't that happen if you set an item of a hashmap (dict)?

Comment: Because testdict = {'just', 'something'} is completely reassigning the value of testdict